# XP virtualbox guest machine Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared folders in XP virtualbox guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/shared-folders-in-xp-virtualbox-guest)

How can I have a shared folder that is accessible on both the guest machine and host machine