# How do i share files between my ubuntu host and xp pro virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared folders in XP virtualbox guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/shared-folders-in-xp-virtualbox-guest)

I'm using Virtualbox 4.1.8 to run Windows XP PRO. I have ironed out all other kinks on my own but I still can't access a file share. The sole purpose of running a VM is to get iTunes for my iPhone but I can't get to my music file from my guest OS, I'm also new to Ubuntu so im not sure if I have done all the updates right or not, any  would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VirtualBox, there should be a set of guest tools you can install on Windows that will allow you to do this.

See http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp9523904 and http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Answer (score 0):

this very easy man follow this steps

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html

this explain with photos

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows

and this from main site

Answer (score 0):

Like the other posts said, install virtual box guest additions.

With virtualbox running, go to "Devices" menu > Shared Folders

Click the folder and plus icon and add the linux host path (Folder Path) you want to share and the windows "folder" (let's suppose it is MyFolder, you can provide any arbitrary name).

After this, you'll be able to access in any explorer window, like this:

\\vboxsrv\MyFolder

Comment: I don't have anything called devices, when the VM is running there are no options at the top of the screen..it just says oracle VM virtualbox is there another way to install guest additions?