# Share folders between windows and ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu-one, virtualbox, windows-xp, shared-folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared folders in XP virtualbox guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/shared-folders-in-xp-virtualbox-guest)

I use virtualbox. My host OS is Ubuntu and the guest one is Windows XP. I want to share a folder between these two OS. But I don't know how. I've added the folder on 'Devices->Shared Folders' window but I don't know how to access it from Windows .

Would you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, go to "Computer", "Network", then choose "VBOXSRV". You will see your shared folder there. If not, then maybe you did not make the folder permanent and rebooted Windows in the meanwhile.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the manual [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders). The command to map a drive in the XP guest is:

```
net use x: \\vboxsvr\sharename
```

Or you can map a drive using the windows tools. The 'server' name is always `vboxsvr`