# How can I access shared folders on an Ubuntu host and a Windows XP guest?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I have installed VirtualBox 4.1.18 on Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm hosting Windows XP.

I want to share a folder between Ubuntu and Windows XP.

I have installed guest additions on the guest machine, but when I'm trying to access the shared folder, I can't find them anywhere.

So, where can I access those shared folders?

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-xp-virtualbox-guest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this guide:
[Shared folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)

The process of creating a shared folder is well explainded in this guide.
In short:
1) In your VM properties set a shared folder on host machine.
2) Boot the guest machine and run the following command:

```
net use x: \\vboxsvr\share
```

where x - is the name of the drive with virtual folded. You may leave it as is, and share - is the name of the folder you've created on host machine.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on Ubuntu Mate 15.04 it doesn't.

mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'
mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxfs'

Answer (score 10):

At least for Ubuntu 15.04 host system and Windows Server 2012 R2 and VirtualBox 4.3.32_Ubuntu r104062, the following works. I assume, it works the same way with other versions of Windows as guest:

1. Boot the Guest operating system in VirtualBox.
2. Select **Devices > Shared Folders** in the VirtualBox menu
3. Choose the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. Select the host folder you want to share
4. Select **Auto Mount**
5. Reboot your guest system
6. Now you will find your shared folder mapped as network drive on Windows. No need to fiddle around with manually booting something on Linux or Windows command line as described in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders).

Comment: Awesome. It works for me. Ubuntu 16.04 and win10 guest. Thanks

Comment: @Abdulaziz Second that.  16.04 host and windows 10 guest. worked first time

Comment: If anyone else is running Mint 19 host and Windows 2000 guest, this process works here also. Cheers Marc.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  However, after not using the VM for a while, and updating Windows, it stopped working.  I had to reinstall the guest additions to get it working again.