# I can not see a shared forlder under VBOXSVR from a XP Guest

Tags: networking, permissions, virtualbox, windows-xp

I made a VirtualBox XP guest from a backup image of my old laptop, which passed away a long time ago. It is working fine on my VitualBox hosts except for being unable to access to the VirtualBox shared folder.

I run VirtualBox on Mint 19, Ubuntu 18.04, and Windows7. I have run several different OS guests on those hosts, and I can share a folder between the hosts and their guests; so, I think my Guest Addition setup was done correctly.

This XP guest can see other hosts on my local network and have access to their share folder except the VBox shared folder. A strange thing is that from this XP guest, I can see VBOXSVR icon on "My Network" window. So, it recognizes VBOXSVR as a host. But, if I double click the icon to get into its shared folder, I find it is totally empty. If I directly type "\\VBOXSVR\share" in the input bar on the "My Network" window, I see a popup window saying it cannot access to the path and I have no permission to it. I tried "net use X: \\VBOXSVR\share", but it replies the error message saying "system error 67 has occurred the network name could not be found." But, all the other OS guests can see the same VBox shared folder without any permission trouble.

So, I made another minimal XP guest from scratch using an XP Install CD. I set all configurations as same as the ones of my XP guest I made from my laptop disk image. The fresh one can share without any problems. So, the only the XP guest of my old laptop image has this trouble.

Please help me to make it have access to VBox shared folder. I would really be glad if I could fix this because I have so many things still running on that laptop image.

A lot of thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access shared folders on an Ubuntu host and a Windows XP guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270394/how-can-i-access-shared-folders-on-an-ubuntu-host-and-a-windows-xp-guest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up shared folders in a Windows Virtualbox guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-virtualbox-guest)

Answer (score 0):

Install the Guest Additions (this solved the problem for me):

- From `Devices` select `Insert Guest Additions CD`
- Navigate to the CD image from `My PC`
- Run `VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe` as administrator and install the tools
- **Reboot** when installation is complete

It should be visible now.