# Share a Folder from Ubuntu to Windows in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu as my main Operating System, but I run Windows in a VirtualBox because some of my programs are not supported, I have Videos, Documents etc on Ubuntu and I would like to access them on Windows without having to copy them to Windows and having two copies of the same file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For sharing folders with a Windows (XP) guest see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-xp-virtualbox-guest. This should also work with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up virtualbox "shared folders" is the way to go.

- You will need to have the VirtualBox *Guest additions* installed
- In the properties of the VM add a shared folder (use a "machine folder"), you can choose any folder **on the host** and give it any name (for the share as seen from the guest)
- Within the guest you go to *My Networking Places -> Entire Network -> VirtualBox Shared Folders* to see it (you can of course assing a Letter to it)

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you mainly need to access files from your virtual guest, you could setup a web-based file hosting service on both machines (such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) that has a good Linux client). This enables file synchronization between two computers, as the virtual guest is technically another "computer". Since everything has to be uploaded to the cloud first, this might not be so practical for larger files.

As a positive side effect you get automatic backups of the files in the cloud in case something goes horribly wrong with the virtual guest.