# How to access hard-drive from Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

recently i installed `windows7` on `oracle VM virtualbox` but I can't get files from my hard drive to the OS installed in VirtualBox.

Is there any way to access files of my hard in VirtualBox?

Comment: You may also be interestend in these Q & A here on the site: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup http://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-xp-virtualbox-guest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a shared folder between your host and virtual machine. It is described here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.