# How to share files to virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, sharing

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and have installed windows 7  in a virtual box, I want to share files to win 7 and vice - versa, So please tell me how to do that, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up shared folders in a Windows XP virtualbox guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-xp-virtualbox-guest)

Comment: you might consider just using `sshfs` to mount a folder in windows. It works wonderfully for my arch/windows 10 setup. Though I can't say for win7 on a vm