# Share files in virtualbox between  Ubuntu host and  WindowsXp guest

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up shared folders in a Windows XP virtualbox guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52773/how-do-i-set-up-shared-folders-in-a-windows-xp-virtualbox-guest)
>   [How to share files on Virtualbox with Windows as a guest?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179669/how-to-share-files-on-virtualbox-with-windows-as-a-guest)

How can I share files between my ubuntu 12.04 and windowsXp running as a virtualBox guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share a directory between the host and the guest machines. For that, one of the ways is going in virtualbox front-end, you select your virtual machine and click on settings. In the settings, you go to shared folders and add the directory you want to share (and the options - read only or read-write)

After you boot your virtual machine, you can get to this shared folder using the Network Places icon and adding a new network place for this folder (will be in `\\VBOXSVR\the_name_you_gave`).

You need the virtualbox guest additions installed in your guest machine to do this. You can download and install them from [virtualbox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Comment: After virtualbox guest additions installation it works fine ! Thank you all.